# cypher 2.0 query using label does not return any nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In the neo4j browser, when I click on * under 'Node Lables' returns nodes of all label types, and when I click on any node, I could see the label name appearing at the top. 
However, the following cypher query is not working.

```
    MATCH (n:`Home`) RETURN n LIMIT 25
    MATCH (n:Home) RETURN n LIMIT 25
```

I have turned on the CYPHER 2.0 property in the neo4j.properties. Do I need to change any other settings?
I see these lablels when I export as JSON

Comment: Is there a typo in your MATCH? That is, you posted *two* MATCH lines - is this an artifact of markdown? Also: Which version of Neo4j are you using? And... Did you upgrade from a 2.0 milestone build to RC1?

Comment: I tried both the options. The labels are created using BatchInserter. I did not upgrade, started at RC1. I posted the same question in [google forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/iTxbrW9Bn68) and looks like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this problem when upgrading. 
Did not manage to find out the problem, but what I did was delete the database and recreate it entirely -> matching on labels worked again.
Of course, deleting the entire database and recreating it is not possible in all situations

Comment: The database I tried is a new one, no upgrade. I switched back to 1.9.3 for now.

Answer (score 0):

Specify START Clause and it works, START n=node(*) where n:Home RETURN n LIMIT 25 . The START clause way worked irrespective of the cypher_parser_version=2.0 property in neo4j.properties commented/uncommented. But I still wonder why your query does not work..