# Matching using labels return no results

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have imported about 5 millions nodes in a Neo4j database on my local computer (Windows 7, neo4j v2.1.3 -**community**) using the batch inserter. Then used 7-zip to create a .tar.gz of my directory graph.db. I uncompressed the hole thing on an Ubuntu server running neo4j v2.1.3-**enterprise**.

I start Neo4j on the server and it loads the database without complaining. It also finds all the nodes, relations and the web browser shows correctly the different labels, relationship types and property keys. I can do different cypher query that work perfectly fine.... until I use labels in the MATCH clause. In that case I never get any result.

This query on my local computer return succesfully some persons and nothing on my linux server.

```
MATCH (n:Person) RETURN n LIMIT 25
```

Also, on the linux server I get result when I run the following

```
MATCH (a)-[:LivesAt]->(b) RETURN a,b LIMIT 25
```

but not when I explicitly specify labels like this

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[:LivesAt]->(b:Address) RETURN a,b LIMIT 25
```

My problem seems related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20358454/cypher-2-0-query-using-label-does-not-return-any-nodes).

Anyone knows why I get this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you run consistency checker as described on bottom of http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/01/22/neo4j-backup-store-copy-and-consistency-check/ on both sides, Windows and Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. The hard drive was full on the Linux computer.